# backbone.js view id tag using information from model

Tags: backbone.js

I am using backbone.js,

I have a model that is formatted like this:

```
{
  username:"name",
  id:"1",
  picture:"image.jpg"
}
```

I want to have a view like this:

```
<div id="1">
    <span class="name">name<span>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

from this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="users-template">
    <span class="name"><%= username %></span>
    <img src="<%= image %>" />      
</script>
```

but I get stuck when it comes to putting the users id into the views id attribute.

```
UserView = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: this.model.id, //this is what I have tried but it doesnt work

    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template($('#users-template').html());
    },

    render: function(){
        ...
    }
})
```

does anyone know how put the current models id into the id attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your model has `picture` but your template uses `image`, they should be the same or you'll get a "missing variable" error from your template.

The `id` attribute on a view is supposed to be the DOM `id` of an existing element; Backbone won't add it to the `el`, Backbone uses it to *find* the `el`. Besides, `this` won't be a view when `id: this.model.id` is executed (`this` will probably be `window` or some other useless thing) and the `model` property isn't set until the view is instantiated anyway.

The [view's `el` is](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and attributes properties, if specified. If not, **el** is an empty `div`.

So drop the `id` from your view and use the default `<div>` for the `el`. Then, in your `render` method, you can set the `id` attribute on `this.el`; also, using a numeric `id` attribute causes trouble with some browsers so you should usually prefix it the `id` with something non-numeric:

```
render: function() {
    this.el.id = 'v' + this.model.get('id');
    this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZBE5z/

Open your console when running the demo and you'll be able to see the HTML that ends up in your view's `this.el`.

Comment: In a perfect world we should be able to use the [View.attributes](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-attributes) with an anonymous function to load the "id".. like `attributes: { "id": function(){ this.model.id; } }` but in this moment `this` is the `DOM element`.. so I also agree that the `id` should be modified in the `render`.

Comment: @fguillen: A small patch to [`Backbone::View#make`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1131) would make that possible, you'd just have to manually iterate over `attributes` instead of simply calling `$(el).attr(attributes)`. `this.model` would be properly set up before `make` is called.

Answer (score 5):

I use that

```
id : function () { 
    return this.model.get("id");
}
```

U can get the model's data only using [".get()"](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get)

> Properties like tagName, id, className, el, and events may also be defined as a function, if you want to wait to define them until runtime. @from Backbonejs.org

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the model isn't set when the JavaScript initially gets executed. Try this:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.id = this.model.id;
    this.template = _.template($('#users-template').html());
},
```

Comment: You are passing model to the view correct? Something like this? `var view = new UserView({ model: model });`